# “Fast-paced” game

Tags: single-word-requests

Does anyone have a good suggestion for how to translate “a fast-paced game”?

I want a word to describe a game where the turns are taken very quickly and there isn’t much time to think. I think I basically want *rapida*, but without the sense that the game will finish quickly and instead that it occurs at a fast pace without time to think and relax.

Another word in English that could fit could be *frenetic*. John Well’s dictionary translates this as *freneza*, but I don’t think that works and maybe it is translating an older medical sense of the English word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surbaze de [tiu ĉi signifo](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fast-paced) de "fast-paced" en la angla mi sugestas:

```
vigla ludo
```

Laŭ PIV  `vigla` estas:

2. Rapidaga, plena de viveco kaj ekscito
3. Rapide kaj aktive progresanta

Tio bone transdonas la senton ĝeneralan. Aliaj ebloj, kun `vico`:

```
rapidvica ludo

ludo kun rapidaj vicoj
```

Por la ideo malantaŭ `frenetic` eble funkcias `senpaŭza`.

Comment: Mi komprenas la vorton "vigla" tiel, ke ĝi postulas ion vivantan. Ekzemple "Mia avino estas vigla, kvankam ŝi estas tre maljuna". Tion vivantan oni povas ankaŭ kompreni figurasence, ekzemple en "vigla trafiko" oni rigardas trafikon kiel vivantan organismon. Sed ludo estas nek vivanta nek rigardebla kiel vivanta organismo.

Comment: @JuhaMetsäkallas Inter la ekzemploj vortaraj estas *"vigla stilo"* kaj "*la akvo vigle elŝprucadis*", ambaŭ Zamenhofaj. Li ankaŭ uzis "*vigla propagando*" kaj por multaj el ni *vigla movado* estas daŭra celo. Temas pri moviĝemo aŭ agemo. Eble rapidvica estas pli esprima por ludantoj.

Comment: Perfekte, dankon!

Answer (score 0):

According to PIV the word [*tempo*](https://vortaro.net/#tempo_kd) has ten defintions. Among these are 9) = *pulso* with an example of *muzikaĵo je du pulsoj* and 10) = *ritmo* with an example of *tempo de marŝo* and a reference to see [*takto*](https://vortaro.net/#takto_kd), which has an example of *promenadi laŭ la takto de tamburo*.

Given those definitions I am inclined to say that both *rapidtempa ludo* and *rapidtakta ludo* will do. Note that there are no hits for either adjective in Tekstaro and only a handful found by Google, but their meaning should nevertheless be easily understood.

Comment: `ritmo` povus boni. Kvankam ĝi temas pri regula afero, ĝi povus taŭgi. Se vicoj estas sufiĉe mallongaj, oni povus senti la ŝanĝigon de ludanto kiel ion ritman. Ne tute regulan, se tamen iel ritman.

Answer (score 0):

'rapidritma' laŭ multaj ekzemploj en Google:
https://bit.ly/39upBOX